# How can I search a list of text strings for more than one word or collection of words?

Tags: powerquery, m

I would like to search a list of text strings, to find which of those strings contain more than one word or phrase, and get the respective row's value. For instance, if I have the following column, how could I search it to find the rows with "red" or "blue jean" in them, and get their values, regardless of case (upper/lower)?

[image]

I know I can use `List.FindText({[Column1]},"red")` to find and return the values of all the rows with "red", but I can't figure out how to find and return the values of all rows with "red" or "blue jean" in them at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of List.Transform and Text.Contains:

```
let
    Source = #table(1,{
                        {"The red barn"},
                        {"A red car"},
                        {"Blue jeans"},
                        {"Green beans"},
                        {"Atlanta"},
                        {"Chicago"}
                       }),

    LookUp = #table(1, {{"red"}, {"blue jean"}}),

    #"Filtered Rows" = 
        Table.SelectRows(
            Source, 
            (r)=> List.AnyTrue(
                    List.Transform(
                        LookUp[Column1], 
                        each Text.Contains(r[Column1], _, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                        )
                )
        )
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

in case of big lookup table you can add a step with `List.Buffer(LookUp[Column1])` before filtering step

Comment: Thanks @Max Zelensky. For the `List.Buffer`, are you saying to add something like `Buffered = List.Buffer(LookUp[Column1]),` in a line before `#"Filtered Rows"`? Or are you saying to add it elsewhere? Then, am I correct that I'd reference `Buffered` in place of `LookUp[Column1]` in the `List.Transform`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Add step with buffer before filtering and then refer to it in List.Transform

Comment: Max, If I want to use an existing table column as the Source and another existing table column as the Lookup, instead of the hard-coded lists values like you set them up here, how would I best do that? I set this up as a function that starts with `(ListToScan, WordsToFind) =>` and tried `Source = ListToScan` and `Lookup = WordsToFind`, I invoke from another query by `FindTextMatchesInList([SourceTable[Column1], LookupTable[Column1]))`. Both columns are type text. I'm certain my syntax is wrong, but I don't know what exactly is wrong. Would you please enlighten me? Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. I used `Source = Table.FromColumns({ListToScan})` and `Lookup = Table.FromColumns({WordsToFind})`.